# Split and stack a multi-value column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to analyze the results from a survey I administered. Each question had checkboxes of possible responses, and users could select as many or as few as they liked.

Data comes in looking like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Result': ['Blue, Yellow, Red',
                'Red',
                'Green, Blue']
})
```

| Result |
| --- |
| Blue, Yellow, Red |
| Red |
| Green, Blue |

Ultimately, I want to know how many times each choice (color) was selected, but using `value_counts()` at this stage tells me the number of times each **exact** choice was made (returns 1,1,1, in this example).

I think I need to make it look like this:

| Result |
| --- |
| Blue |
| Yellow |
| Red |
| Red |
| Green |
| Blue |

So I need to split each index on a comma, using `str.split(',')` but I can't guarantee how many choices will have been selected.

Everything I've found so far deals with splitting one column into multiple columns, but I want to split one column and stack the results into one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df.Result.str.split(', ', expand = True).stack().reset_index(drop = True).value_counts()

Blue      2
Red       2
Yellow    1
Green     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had seen `expand=True`, but didn't know that `stack()` would ignore the resulting NAs.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `str.split` + `explode` + `value_counts`:

```
out = df['Result'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Blue      2
Red       2
Yellow    1
Green     1
Name: Result, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `explode`. Seems written to do exactly what I'm trying to do here.